# Why does this code result in a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

In the code below, I don't expect memory to continuously increase, but it does, according to chrome debugger.

In the middle of the loop, I await 10 milliseconds which is enough for the previous timeout to finish. Yet still the memory doesn't seem to be freed. Why is that?

```
while (true) {
    let giantArray = Array(100000).fill().map(() => Math.random());
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
    setTimeout(() => {
        giantArray[3] = 3; // If I don't reference giantArray, there is no leak
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly happens in execution (is the GC fast enough to remove the closures and clean the arrays?) but this code is really begging for problems. **Never** use timeouts to wait for task execution.

Comment: " _I await 10 milliseconds which is enough for the previous timeout to finish_ " Why do you think that ?

Comment: When I add console logs, I can confirm that. Memory leak still happens with console.log

Answer (score 0):

You have a while-true loop there; and the first statement reads:

```
while (true) {
  let giantArray = Array(100000).fill().map(() => Math.random());
```

So you are creating a **new** giantArray in each loop iteration. To be thrown away immediately thereafter. And you are really surprised that this moves you into "out of memory"?

In other words: it doesn't really matter what you do afterwards. Your code creates that huge array; fills it (!); throws it away. And then does the same thing again and again.

So even when garbage collection would work properly here (and it doesn't);  it is still possible to create garbage on such a high rate that the garbage collector can't keep up!

Comment: Without the setTimeout but still referencing the giantArray, the memory leak isn't there